# How to ignore model field validators in the Django admin?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have the following model:

```
class Vote(models.Model):
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=1, validators=[MaxValueValidator(5, message="Hi"))
    ... snipped ...
```

How can I **ignore** the validators if the votes field is being incremented in the **admin** section?

Can I override the field to ignore validators? Or is there a way to **not** call full_clean() method to prevent the validators from running.